# Count the divisors of n with particular property

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Take $n = \prod_{i=1}^r {p_i}^{\alpha_i}$, where each $p_i$ is a prime and $\alpha_i\geq 1$.

How many divisors of $n$, not equal to $n$, contain at least one $p_i$ with the corresponding multiplicity $\alpha_i$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if your posted answer is correct, but here's one way to think about the problem. How many divisors are there where no prime occurs with maximal multiplicity? This is easy to compute as $\prod_m \alpha_m$ since you can choose exponents between $0$ and $\alpha_m-1$ for each prime divisor, each giving rise to a unique product for each choice. Then how many total divisors are there? This is $\prod_m (\alpha_m + 1)$. The difference between these two quantities is the answer you want, and subtract $1$ if you want to exclude $n$ as a divisor of itself.

Comment: I think you are right, and your answer is definitely better than mine :)

Comment: You forgot to subtract 1 for n, but that's alright.

Comment: Whoops I forgot you didn't want to include $n$. I edited to mention the subtract $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\operatorname{rad}(n)=\prod_{i=1}^rp_i$ be the largest squarefree number dividing n. Then the answer is $d(n)-d(\operatorname{rad}(n)).$

Edit: You didn't want to include n, so subtract 1 unless n is squarefree.

Comment: $d$ is the number of divisors, right? Then isn't $d(\mathrm{rad}(n)) = \sum_k\binom{r}{k}$? If so I don't think this is right.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn: It's $2^r$. My answer is essentially the same as user2566092's, though in different terms.

Comment: Alright then, I selected user2566092 (despite his/her awful name!) for their answer, it seems more natural to me, but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

My answer is
$$
\sum_{k=2}^r \binom{r}{k} \left( 1 + \sum_{l=1}^{k-1} \prod_m(\alpha_m-1)^{\binom{k-1}{l}} \right) + r - 1
$$
where

- $1$ corresponds to all divisors that combine only (at least 2) primes with multiplicity,
- $r-1 = \binom{r}{1} - \binom{r}{r}$ corresponds to each single ${p_i}^{\alpha_i}$ not included previously minus the term that corresponds to $n$,
- $l$ corresponds to the number of primes with multiplicity in a number that contains $k$ primes, and $\binom{k-1}{l}$ stands for how many times each prime would then not appear with multiplicity.

Is this correct?

Answer (score -3):

If $ \ n=(p_1)^{a_1} \ \times \ldots \times (p_r)^{a_r} \ $
then the required answer is

$$ (a_1+1)(a_2+1)\ldots(a_{(r-1)}+1) \ + \ (a_1+1)(a_2+1)\ldots (a_{(r-2)}+1)(a_r+1) \ + \ \ldots \ +(a_1+1)(a_3+1)\ldots (a_{(r-2)}+1)(a_{(r-1)}+1)(a_r+1) \ + \ (a_2+1)(a_3+1)\ldots(a_{(r-2)}+1)(a_{(r-1)}+1)(a_r+1) \ - \ r \ ; $$

the sum contains $ \ r \ $ summands.

Example for $n=24=2^3\cdot3$, the numbers are $2^3 \ , \ 2\cdot3 \ , \ 2^2\cdot3 \ , \ 3$ . According to the formula the number of such numbers is $ \ (3+1)+(1+1)-2 \ =  \ 4 \ $ .

Comment: Hmm.. what? :) Sorry, I don't know if this is a joke or not.

Comment: if you want to keep p_1 with exponent a_1,then you can have (a_2+1) options for the prime P_2 (namely 1,p_2,.....,p_2^(a_1+1)),similarly you get (a_3+1) options forp_3 and so on.So in total there are (a_2+1)....(a_r+1)-1 options(i have subtracted 1 since n is not to be included)..a_1 means a suffix 1 and p^a means p to the power a